# Below two different codes gives me two different outputs in Java

Tags: java, readline

See the below two code and let me know why it is printing like that this is java language

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file path"));
while(br.readLine()!= null) {
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
}
br.close();
```

This code doesn't print complete file content, however if i use below code it prints complete content of file..please explain

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath"));
String str;
while((str=br.readLine())!= null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
br.close();
```

Comment: Because you are calling readLine() twice in the first examle and only printing it in one case. readLine() - as the name heavily implies - reads a line. So if you call it twice you will have read 2 lines and if you only print one of those you will only print half the file.

Answer (score 5):

Simple: you read lines twice from the `BufferedReader`, by calling `br.readLine()` twice in your `while` loop. First a line is read in the condition part (`while (br.readLine()!=null)`) and later again to print it (`...println(br.readLine())`).

A line that is read is gone from the buffer.

In your second code part, the line is stored to `str` in the condition part. That `str` is later also used to print the line.

Comment: "You read each line twice" is exactly what the code is _not_ doing. Instead, it reads the _next_ line when it _should_ read the same line again (according to what OP seems to expect).

Comment: greatest name on stackoverflow

Comment: @tobias_k nice! although i think everybody knows what he is trying to say :)

Answer (score 2):

You are reading line twice using `br.readLine()` in first code first in while condition and second in `System.out.println(br.readLine())` that's why it always prints `2,4,6,8...` lines and in second code you are reading once and its storing in `str` variable and printing `str` that's whys its printing whole file.